# In an indiscrete topology, does the empty set have any limit points?

Tags: general-topology

Since the intersection of any set with $\emptyset$ is $\emptyset$, it does not seem like $\phi$ has any limit point. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. No matter what topology you put, $\emptyset$ has no limit points.

Comment: For $\emptyset$, use `\emptyset`; for $\varnothing$ use `\varnothing`.

Comment: the empty set has a unique topology, and of course it has no limit points since $\emptyset$ has no points at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty set has no limit points since no set can have non-empty intersection with $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\emptyset$ has at least one limit point, say $x$. Then there exist a sequence $(x_n)$ in $\emptyset$ which converge to $x.$ That is each $x_n\in\emptyset.$ This gives if empty set has a limit point it is not empty which contradicts to its definition. Hence??

Comment: That's not the definition of limit point. A limit point of a set $S$ is a point $x$ such that $U\cap (S\setminus \{x\}) \neq \varnothing$ for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$. It does not follow that there is a sequence in $S$ converging to $x$ - and sometimes, such a sequence does not exist. If we were dealing with metric spaces, such a sequence would necessarily exist.

Comment: After a long time now I can understand your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would appear to be correct.   And since it contains all its limit points (vacuously),  it's closed. Additionally,  this appears to be true in any topology.